# WordPress content duplicated on web pages after html end tag </html>

Tags: html, wordpress

I have two pages that display posts by category.  At the bottom of the web page is a duplicate listing of the content for each post.  This data is being displayed after the html end tag `</html>`.

[Example Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iXid.png)

My pages:
http://thecollegeroar.com/blog/category/admissions/
http://thecollegeroar.com/blog/category/financial-aid/

```
<?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying archive pages
     *
     * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
     * @since 1.0
     * @version 1.0
     */

    //get_header(); ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <?php 
            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $path .= "/loadLinks.php";
            include_once($path);
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
           $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
           $path .= "/header.php";
           include_once($path);
        ?>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="links">
                <?php 
                   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                   $path .= "/collegeLinks.php";
                   include_once($path);
                ?>
            </div>

            <div id="article_blog">
                <div class="wrap">

                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <header class="page-header">
                            <?php
                                the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                                the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                            ?>
                        </header><!-- .page-header -->
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                        <?php
                        if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                            <?php
                            /* Start the Loop */
                            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                                /*
                                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                                 */
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

                            endwhile;

                            the_posts_pagination( array(
                                'prev_text' => twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) . '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>',
                                'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ),
                                'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . ' </span>',
                            ) );

                        else :

                            //get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'none' );

                        endif; ?>

                        </main><!-- #main -->
                    </div><!-- #primary -->
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div><!-- .wrap -->
            </div><!-- article -->
            <div id="news">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <ul>
                            <li><img    src="/Images/Social/Twitter_570625.png" 
                                width="50px"
                                height="auto"></li>
                            <li>The College Roar Live</li>  
                        </ul>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="twitter">
                        <a  class="twitter-timeline" 
                            href="https://twitter.com/thecollegeroar?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw
                            "data-tweet-limit='5'">
                            Tweets by thecollegeroar
                        </a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $path .= "/footer.php";
            include_once($path);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line you have a syntax error, try to fix it like this:

```
<a  class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/thecollegeroar?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" data-tweet-limit='5'>
```

Comment: I removed the twitter elements and I am still have the extra content at bottom of page.      http://thecollegeroar.com/blog/category/financial-aid/

Comment: when I open the URL, there is empty site

Answer (score 0):

I restored the twentyseventeen theme with the original code and this removed the extra details after the end tag.